# Sort list with string date [Kotlin]

Tags: sorting, kotlin

I have arraylist **`typeBeanArrayList`** where element is some like a date: for example:

```
[30-03-2012, 28-03-2013, 31-03-2012, 2-04-2012, ...]
```

How can I sort in **descending order.**

Code:

```
typeBeanArrayList = database.getSingleCustomerDetail(c_id!!) //get data from SQlite database

creditListAdapter = CreditListAdapter(typeBeanArrayList)
rv_credit_list!!.adapter = creditListAdapter //Bind data in adapter
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I don't know much about kotlin but I'm pretty sure you could write your own comparator  http://kotlination.com/kotlin/kotlin-sort-list-of-objects-with-comparator-example

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Thank you @svkaka for information.

I just notice one line from @svkaka answer : **`.sortByDescending { it.length }`**.

and i changes in my code like :

```
typeBeanArrayList.sortByDescending{it.date}
```

Sorting is perfectly work.

Comment: How does it sort by date ? This answer is wrong it simply takes String length and sorts it in descending order

Comment: Really it doesn't work for date format, this solution checks for string as date it it.date is not  a Date object

Comment: i dont know how but this works. I wonder if there are any failing edge cases.

Comment: i believe you need to convert to a date object; otherwise you are comparing strings; might be wrong though

Answer (score 12):

If you have a list of `String`s representing dates, one way to sort them in descending order is:

```
val dates = listOf("30-03-2012", "28-03-2013", "31-03-2012", "2-04-2012")

val dateTimeFormatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")

val result = dates.sortedByDescending {
    LocalDate.parse(it, dateTimeFormatter)
}

println(result)
```

This will print:

```
[28-03-2013, 2-04-2012, 31-03-2012, 30-03-2012]
```

Note that `sortedByXXX` methods return a new List, i.e., they don't sort *in place*

Comment: yes, the first item belongs to year 2013, all the others belong to 2012

Comment: this is long way i just use one line : **`typeBeanArrayList.sortByDescending{it.date}`** and this is work perfectly. thanks for your response.

Comment: i just little bit confuse i just watch dates but there is also consider month for descending.

Comment: Yep, your code works and is shorter, and that's because your list doesn't contain `String`s but instances of some kind of type that has a `date` property (returning a `Date` or `LocalDate` object, I guess)

Comment: NO. In bean class i can define date as a string like **`var date : String? = ""`**. also i add date as a string. also i retrieve date as a string.

Comment: @MR.K I'm sorry but I'm not sure I fully understood: is `date` of type `String`? If that's the case, then you're sorting *alphabetically* instead of *chronologically* (which may be what you want, though)

Comment: requires api 26+

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
[30-03-2012, 28-03-2013, 31-03-2012, 2-04-2012, ...].sortDescending()
```

if you want to sort by param use in this case length

```
[30-03-2012, 28-03-2013, 31-03-2012, 2-04-2012, ...].sortByDescending { it.length }
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to sort by *chronological* descending order, which means they can't use `.sortDescending()` as it will sort by *alphabetical* order. They need to use `sortByDescending`, transforming the String to a Date object, which can then be sorted as desired

Comment: i just use **`typeBeanArrayList.sortByDescending{it.date}`** and data will show in Descending order. Thank you @svkaka

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this if you are using a custom model

```
typeBeanArrayList.sortedWith(compareByDescending<YourModel> { it.date() })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data class YouModel(val startDate: String? = null) {

  val BY_DATE_ORDER =
            compareByDescending<YourModel> {
                val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
                var convertedDate = Date()
                try {
                    convertedDate = it.startDate?.let { it1 -> format.parse(it1) } as Date
                } catch (e: ParseException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

                convertedDate
            }
    }



yourList<YourModel>?.sortedWith(YourModel.BY_DATE_ORDER)
```

This works for me. I created a descending comparator using the function to transform value to a Comparable instance for comparison. I converted the string date to date before applying the sorting function.