# How to sort dates by Month & Day in Kotlin

Tags: android, date, sorting, kotlin

i have a date with format `date = 01-06-2021`. I sort it by using `list.sortedBy { it.date }` kotlin function .
But it gives me like this

```
01-06-2021
01-07-2021
01-08-2021
02-06-2021
02-07-2021
02-08-2021
```

i need to sort like below

```
01-06-2021
02-06-2021
01-07-2021
02-07-2021
01-08-2021
02-08-2021
```

Sort it by month instead of by day.
Do i need to split the whole date with day , month ,year and then sort? It has lot of data to be done, these comes from firebase realtime database. Any suggestion?

Comment: See if this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54925794/sort-list-with-string-date-kotlin) helps you

Answer (score 1):

`list.sortedBy { it.date }` will not work because date is in string format. You have to convert string to date like following"

```
list.sortedBy {
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
            sdf.parse(it.date).time
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to achieve can simply be done by the `Date` object itself, since the default class declaration has already implemented `Comparable<Date>` in your desired way:

```
list.sorted()
```

You can also sort your dates based on their epoch millis:

```
list.sortedBy { it.time }
```